# javascript - get object data

Tags: javascript

In my rails application, i have a form where user has to select some items via checkbox. I want to display the selected items' information in a div.

I am currently using javascript to do that.

So in form, when user clicks in a checkbox, i pass the 'this' obj as parameter to a javascript function which then appends the 'this.value' to the end the div.

However appending the 'this.value' displays only the id of of the selected item. I also want to display the other data of the selected item in the div.

Is that possible in javascript? How do i get other information of the 'this' obj, apart from 'this.value'?

Many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Please find code below-

```
#in my form:
<input id="id_<%= item.id %>" name="submission[item_ids][]" onclick="addtoselected(this);" value="<%= item.id %>" type="checkbox" />
```

javascript code:

```
function addtoselected(obj){
    if(obj.checked==true){
    var s = '<div>' + obj.value + '</div>';
    $j('#selected_recs').append(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put up some code that you have so far.  Preferably on http://jsfiddle.net.  It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want is in a label, you could loop through all labels and check which one has the id in his for attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use the contents of `this.value` to lookup the information you need.  You could send it as a parameter to a server-side script to get its information back in JSON format, or if you already have an existing javascript object store, you could look up the item's information from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..will have a look at JSON and try using it